# SourceGenerator/IncrementalGenerator Debugging

Tags: sourcegenerators

We used to be able to debug Source Generators using this tip from https://github.com/amis92/csharp-source-generators#tips--tricks in VS 2019.

We have upgraded to VS 2022 (update 2) and this no longer works.

Has this feature been removed or have the instructions changed?

I have checked github and found nothing productive.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in roslyn and it got fixed recently. please check this issue link https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/issues/850
PR link is https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/pull/896